# Promises: How to execute async methods in parallel then execute method

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm using Q.js for promises. In the following code, each method makes an ajax call and then returns a promise. Everything works as expected with each method executing and completing before the next begins:

```
functionOne().then(junctionTwo)
                .then(functionThree)
                .then(doSomethingElse);
```

What I would really like however is for functionOne, functionTwo and functionThree to all be executed simultaneously and "doSomethingElse" should be executed only when the first 3 methods are complete.

How do you accomplish this with promises/Q.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the now-standardized `Promise.all()` to tell you when an array of promises are all done:

```
Promise.all([functionOne(), functionTwo(), functionThree()]).then(function(results) {
    // all are done here
    doSomethingElse();
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error in at least one promise here
});
```

Or, if you're still using the Q library syntax, then you can use `Q.all()` which does the same thing.

```
Q.all([functionOne(), functionTwo(), functionThree()]).then(function(results) {
    // all are done here
    doSomethingElse();
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error in at least one promise here
});
```

You should know that in node.js or the browser, there is no "simultaneously" because JS is single threaded (outside of webWorkers which are not being used here).  But, if your operations are asynchronous (which I assume since they return promises), then they can all three be in flight at the same time though only one is executing at any given moment.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Looks like a serial downvoter since question and all answers all got downvotes.  Weird to have no explanation.  Kind of hard to improve your answer if nobody offers any rationale for why they think it deserve a downvote.  Downvotes can be just punitive or they can encourage improvement that benefits the whole community by explaining what you think is wrong.

Comment: Maybe he did punish you for answering (instead of voting to close) a badly researched question? We cannot know, votes are subjective. I can only assert you that there is objectively nothing wrong with the contents of your answer, you got my +1.

Comment: How is that a badly researched question? Any question that has a known answer could be called "badly researched" by someone who has the answer, couldn't it? Thanks to jfriend00 and kouak. I didn't know this had been added to the language.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Promise.all` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
Promise.all([functionOne(), junctionTwo(), functionThree()]).then(doSomethingElse)
```